# Trouble running two NEMA 17's with a joystick

Tags: programming, stepper-motor

So I'm trying to make a motorized dobsonian telescope using two NEMA 17 motors with Easy Driver boards. I want to control the x and y axis with a joystick. I found a code that ran one with a joystick and I tried to modify it by copying the loop and adding the y-axis. Well only the X-axis moves and it only turns CCW.

Can someone run over this and see if they see the issue that I can't? Thank you

```
/*This program is designed to control two nema 17 boards with easy driver board with a joystick on a Nano.
My specific use is to control the X and Y axis of a homemade telescope

considered open source, feel free to do whatever with it.
*/





#define step_pinX 3                                                             // Pin 3 connected to Steps pin on EasyDriver       X-AXIS
#define dir_pinX 2                                                              // Pin 2 connected to Direction pin                 X-AXIS
#define MS1X 5                                                                  // Pin 5 connected to MS1 pin                       X-AXIS
#define MS2X 4                                                                  // Pin 4 connected to MS2 pin                       X-AXIS
#define SLEEPX 6                                                                // Pin 6 connected to SLEEP pin                     X-AXIS
#define step_pinY 7                                                             // Pin 7 connected to Steps pin on EasyDriver         Y-AXIS
#define dir_pinY 8                                                              // Pin 8 connected to Direction pin                   Y-AXIS
#define MS1Y 9                                                                  // Pin 9 connected to MS1 pin                         Y-AXIS
#define MS2Y 10                                                                 // Pin 10 connected to MS2 pin                        Y-AXIS
#define SLEEPY 11                                                               // Pin 11 connected to SLEEP pin                      Y-AXIS
#define XPin A0                                                                // Pin A0 connected to joystick x axis              x-AXIS
#define YPin A1                                                                // Pin A1 connected to joystick y axis                Y-AXIS
#define JoySwitch 12                                                            // Pin 12 connected to joystick button  
#define Limit01 22                                                              // Pin 22 connected to limit switch
#define Limit02 23                                                              // Pin 23 connected to limit switch

int stepSpeed = 10;                                                            // speed of stepper motor


void setup() {
   pinMode(MS1X, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(MS2X, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(dir_pinX, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(step_pinX, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(SLEEPX, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(MS1Y, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(MS2Y, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(dir_pinY, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(step_pinY, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(SLEEPY, OUTPUT);

   pinMode(Limit01, INPUT);
   pinMode(Limit02, INPUT);

   pinMode(JoySwitch,INPUT_PULLUP);

   digitalWrite(SLEEPX, HIGH);                                                  // Wake up EasyDriver
   delay(5);                                                                    // Wait for EasyDriver wake up
   digitalWrite(SLEEPY, HIGH);                                                  // Wake up EasyDriver
   delay(5);                                                                    // Wait for EasyDriver wake up


/* Configure type of Steps on EasyDriver:
// MS1X MS2X MS1Y MS2Y
//
// LOW LOW = Full Step //
// HIGH LOW = Half Step //
// LOW HIGH = A quarter of Step //
// HIGH HIGH = An eighth of Step //
*/

   digitalWrite(MS1X, LOW);                                                      // Configures to Full Steps
   digitalWrite(MS2X, LOW);                                                      // Configures to Full Steps
   digitalWrite(MS1Y, LOW);                                                      // Configures to Full Steps
   digitalWrite(MS2Y, LOW);                                                      // Configures to Full Steps

}

void loop() {
  if (!digitalRead(JoySwitch)) {                                                 // Check joystick switch position
  delay(500);                                                                    // delay for debouncing
  switch (stepSpeed) {                                                          // Check current value of step_speed and change it
    case 1:
    stepSpeed=10;                                                               // slow speed
    break;
    case 3:
    stepSpeed=1;                                                                // fast speed 
    break;
    case 10:
    stepSpeed=3;                                                                // medium speed
    break;
  }
  }

  if (analogRead(XPin)> 712){                                                     //if joystick is moved left
    if (!digitalRead(Limit01))  {}                                               // check is limit switch is activated

    else {                                                                       // if limit switch is not activated, move motor clockwise
      digitalWrite(dir_pinX, LOW);                                               // (HIGH = anti-clockwise / LOW = clockwise)
      digitalWrite(step_pinX, HIGH);
      delay(stepSpeed);
      digitalWrite(step_pinX, LOW);
      delay(stepSpeed);
    }
  }

if (analogRead(XPin) < 312){                                                     //if joystick is moved left
    if (!digitalRead(Limit02))  {}                                               // check is limit switch is activated

    else {                                                                       // if limit switch is not activated, move motor clockwise
      digitalWrite(dir_pinX, HIGH);                                               // (HIGH = anti-clockwise / LOW = clockwise)
      digitalWrite(step_pinX, HIGH);
      delay(stepSpeed);
      digitalWrite(step_pinX, LOW);
      delay(stepSpeed);

    }
    }   
    if (analogRead(YPin)> 712){                                                     //if joystick is moved left
    if (!digitalRead(Limit01))  {}                                               // check is limit switch is activated

    else {                                                                       // if limit switch is not activated, move motor clockwise
      digitalWrite(dir_pinY, LOW);                                               // (HIGH = anti-clockwise / LOW = clockwise)
      digitalWrite(step_pinY, HIGH);
      delay(stepSpeed);
      digitalWrite(step_pinY, LOW);
      delay(stepSpeed);
    }
  }

if (analogRead(YPin) < 312){                                                     //if joystick is moved left
    if (!digitalRead(Limit02))  {}                                               // check is limit switch is activated

    else {                                                                       // if limit switch is not activated, move motor clockwise
      digitalWrite(dir_pinY, HIGH);                                               // (HIGH = anti-clockwise / LOW = clockwise)
      digitalWrite(step_pinY, HIGH);
      delay(stepSpeed);
      digitalWrite(step_pinY, LOW);
      delay(stepSpeed);

    }
    }         

}
```

Comment: how many limit switches do you have? ... you are reading the same switch with X and Y code

Comment: you code has unnecessary convolution .... `if(!digitalRead(Limit02))  {}   else { .... }` is same as `if(digitalRead(Limit02))  { .... }`